# Static file not served through IIS but serving through localhost - ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I am new to programming, and I was able to solve most of the issues all by myself. But this issue goes over my head.

I am using Visual Studio to run my app locally. When I click on "IIS Express" within VS to run the app, the app is opening in a browser with url `http://localhost:1234/` and serving static files.

However when I use IIS to host my app, like when I type `myapp.com` in my browser, I am seeing website in plain text. And no static files (css, js) are being served.

Not sure what is causing the issue. I googled for long time and read lot of posts, but most of them are asking to check if IIS has static role service turned or suggesting to use `app.UseStaticFiles()` within `startup.cs` file. Which in my case is done.

program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {
                  webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
              })
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "access it through my IIS"? Aren't you using IIS or IIS Express when you're using `localhost:5001`?

Comment: ...then I realized you're using ASP.NET Core so you're probably using Kestrel when running it locally. If so, then I suggest you try to make it work using IIS Express locally first (or try to reproduce the problem there).

Comment: Hi @Dai, I am using Visual studio to run my app locally. When I click on "IIS express" within VS to run the app, the app is opening in a browser with url http://localhost:1234/. and serving static files. However when I use IIS to host my app. Like when i type myapp.com in url, i am seeing website in plain text in my browser. And no static file being served.

Comment: Did you follow this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Yes @Oguz we did everything as in the article

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know that when we publish it to "files and folder" from Visual studio, any changes that we make in Visual studio will not go through to published folder. Because of this reason "app.UseStaticFiles();" command (that I wrote after publishing) is not passed on to published folder. I had to delete the published folder and republish to make everything work fine.