# Deployed .NET Core MVC Application to IIS, App is running, but Static files in wwwroot are not being loaded

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I deployed my .NET 5 MVC to IIS. The app is running, but files stored in wwwroot directory are not being loaded in the browser.

Comment: A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606531/static-file-not-served-through-iis-but-serving-through-localhost-asp-net-core)

Comment: That didn't work for me. When I run it locally with IIS Express, it runs fine. The problem happens when I deploy to IIS

Comment: Could you please tell me which error the F12 develop tool's shows? 404 ?

Comment: I already fixed it. For some reasons, the files were showing in the project, but they were not being published. So, I removed and added them to the project again. That resolved the issue

Comment: I'm glad that you solved it by yourself. I suggest you could try to write an reply and mark it as answer. It will help other folks who faces the same issue to find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, the files were showing in the project, but they were not being published. So, I removed and added them to the project again. That resolved the issue